# finding point on a line where distance to point e (r) is equal to b-e

Tags: trigonometry

i have two lines (a-b) and and (c-d) and also point e. all points have coordinates (x,y). point e is the center point of a perfect circle. please note that these lines do intersect at some point.

the distance between point b and e = r.
i need to find a point (f) on the line (c-d) where the distance of line (f-e) = r

how would i be able to do this? in your answer please include the general formulas aswell as an example. any help is greatly appreciated!

edit: added example picture
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi6Yn.png)

Comment: Explain the meaning of the circle. Send a drawing

Comment: the circle isn't really drawn however, point b and point f will be on the edge of a circle, so after calculating point f i can draw an arc between point b and f

Comment: @Raffaele i added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Use capital letters for points

Draw a circle with centre $E$ and radius $r$. The intersection point(s) of this circle with the line $CD$ are point(s) $F$

If you add actual coordinates I can show you formulas and procedure
$A(220, 270),B(127, 420),C(400, 124),D(140, 990),E(140.24, 87.131)$

1. Find $EB=\sqrt{(x_E-x_B)^2+(y_E-y_B)^2}=47.034$
2. Find equation of the circle with centre $E$ and radius $EB$
   $(x-x_E)^2+(y-y_E)^2=47.034^2$
3. Find equation of line $CD$ that is
   $y-y_C=\frac{y_D-Y_C}{x_D-x_C}\,(x-x_c)$
4. Solve the system formed by circle and line $CD$

   Formulas for $x$ and $y$ are quite long

you can find them [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OH4Z.jpg)

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: is it possible to calculate this without drawing a circle?

Comment: @FrankK Yep! Send me the data and I'll show you

Comment: a: Point2D.Double[10.0, 10.0] b: Point2D.Double[127.0, 42.0] c: Point2D.Double[28.0, 113.0] D: Point2D.Double[140.0, 99.0] E: Point2D.Double[119.4339371856623, 69.66341716492224]

where [x,y]

Comment: i hope this data is clear enough? otherwise ill write another print function for more clear data

Comment: It is impossible! Point $E$ is closer to $AB$ than to $CD$. No points of $CD$ can have the distance equal to $EB$

Comment: what about this dataset: a: Point2D.Double[10.0, 10.0] b: Point2D.Double[127.0, 42.0] c: Point2D.Double[28.0, 113.0] D: Point2D.Double[162.0, 71.0] E: Point2D.Double[121.80629622743231, 60.989479418450635]

Comment: also, could you include the formulas? im curious

Comment: No way @FrankK These are even worse :)  https://imgur.com/l8ysghq

Comment: @FrankK I am curious to know what's going on. What are these data and why you do not see where  the points are in the plane :)

Comment: im writing a program where you can draw an arc between two lines, however if one of the lines is too long to draw a perfect arc between them, it has to be shortened, the data comes from points i've selected on the screen

Comment: this data should be better: a: Point2D.Double[220.0, 27.0] b: Point2D.Double[181.0, 107.0] c: Point2D.Double[40.0, 124.0] D: Point2D.Double[201.0, 124.0] E: Point2D.Double[140.2430717467271, 87.13099747652947]

Comment: thank you for this, i eventually figured it out, using the circle method you showed in your original post i have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

From your diagram it appears a tangential contact but not cutting of these lines by radius as a secant is required. Draw two lines parallel to $ ab,cd $ with minimum distance between them $r$ so that inside intersection point is $e$ and next draw the contacting circle of radius $r$ and center $e$.

Comment: the circle is not actually drawn, i've added the circle in the example picture to show that point e is the circle's centerpoint. the point is to calculate the position of point f where the length of line f-e == b-e

Comment: also i dont really understand your answer, could you add an example?